# Static Library Code Phase Project header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

i read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Setting%20the%20Role%20of%20a%20Header%20File.html

that you are able to set different class headers in your library to be public / private / project. In my Library i set one of my classes to project.

But for some reason, if i include the library in another project, i am able to use the class which meant to be only project related. Does somebody know how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that the public/private/project stuff just affects what is copied during an *Archive* so that only the right `.h` files are "delivered" with the `.a` file.

When using the static library project (i.e. via the source tree) you have access to all header files (you might need to set-up the *Header Search Path*, however).  There is no way of "protecting" headers from the project that uses the static library project and little reason to either.

Comment: Ahh ok, so in the end if a archive my Library and there´s one class header set to be "project", i am not able to use this class in another project where my library is linked against...

Comment: Yes; it's used to define which headers are delivered with a binary install of the library.